# Making directional arrow line symbol in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, line

How can I create a `directional arrow line symbol` **in ArcGIS Pro**?

On [this page](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/styles-and-symbols/creating-line-symbols.htm), they explain how to create a `directional arrow line symbol` in ArcMap. However, I'm using ArcGIS Pro and its [documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/layer-properties/symbol-effects.htm) doesn't seem to mention this kind of symbology at all.

Here's an image of what I'm looking for (copied from the ArcMap's documentation).

[image: Directional arrow line symbol1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this answer I will assume you will start from simple line without markers.

- Right-click the layer and go to Symbology, then click on the line symbol

[image]

- Go to `Properties -> Structure -> Layers -> Add symbol layer` of type Marker `-> Add effect ->` Select `Dash effect`

[image]

- Go to `Layers -> Font -> ESRI Arrowhead ->` select your favorite arrow head and click OK

[image]

- Select the arrowhead color that matches the line color. Under Dash effect, select the forth type from top (dot-shaped dash).

[image]

- Under the `Dash template`, write `1 30` (you can adjust it as you like). Under `At line ends`, select Half gap, if you want to rotate the arrow, you need to adjust the rotation to 180 degree, and click apply. Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! Btw, do you know why the ArcGIS pro documentation is so scarce? The documentation for ArcGIS Desktop had a bunch of these little step-by-step screenshots that helped a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. I don’t know why the ArcGIS Pro documentation does not provide detailed explanation as the ArcGIS for Desktop, but with careful reading of the help you provided in your question, you can get a hint of how to create the directional style.